# Selenium web driver: How do I click on the button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<button style="margin: 8px 5px 0 0; height: 40px;" 
class="gprospect_linkedin_button gprospect_linkedin_button_style_medium"> 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">Get email
</button>
```

Tried the code below but element cannot be found:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('gprospect_linkedin_button').click()
```

Comment: Check if the button is inside `<iframe>`. You can also try adding [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: no it's not in iframe

Comment: Which button exactly do you want to click? Can you share your scenario?

Comment: @Andersson OP's this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714921/selenium-web-driver-how-do-i-click-on-the-button/52715015#comment92355926_52715015) might help.

Comment: @DebanjanB , you're trying to solve issue described in comment to another answer, but not initial issue, described in question. Please leave appropriate comment below Infern0 answer or add solution for *issue described in question*

Answer (score 0):

The actual class name is **'gprospect_linkedin_button gprospect_linkedin_button_style_medium'**

*find_element_by_class_name* function is designed to get the element by the full class-name.

You can try to locate it with xpath like this:

```
//button[contains(@class, 'gprospect_linkedin_button')];
```

Comment: Actually `gprospect_linkedin_button gprospect_linkedin_button_style_medium`, are two classes. The OP used the method correctly.

Comment: find_element_by_class_name or find_elements_by_class_name does not work with multiple class names. the locator should specify the full class name, if you wish to grab a partial name from the full class, use xpath.

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class, 'gprospect_linkedin_button')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

Comment: @Infern0 True, it doesn't work with multiple class names. However the OP used only one class.

Comment: @usertool xpath which i provided is working. So the button which you provided is not present, or class name has been dynamically changed.

Comment: @Infern0 i check the source, the class name is static

Comment: Passing single class name to `find_element_by_class_name` is absolutely correct usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath `starts-with` function to solve this issue. 
like:

```
//*[starts-with(., 'gprospect_linkedin_button')]
```

Comment: How can it solve the issue?! This XPath won't select required button

Comment: if in that page have only one linkedin button then this xpath will helps. Please read about start-with function for more details

Comment: I know how `starts-with` works :) And I can advice you to do the same :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the configuration details (within your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714921/selenium-web-driver-how-do-i-click-on-the-button/52715015#comment92355926_52715015) update) ...

```
(Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.37*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.37*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

- You are using *chrome=69.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.37* and the *Chrome Browser v69.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Use the following line of code to invoke `click()` on the desired element:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='gprospect_linkedin_button gprospect_linkedin_button_style_medium'][normalize-space()='Get email']").click()
  ```
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Update A

As you are still seeing `NoSuchElementException` after the binary update you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other lines of code
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='gprospect_linkedin_button gprospect_linkedin_button_style_medium'][normalize-space()='Get email']"))).click()
```

---

### Update B

As you are still unable to `click()` you need to use `execute_script()` method as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other lines of code
myElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='gprospect_linkedin_button gprospect_linkedin_button_style_medium'][normalize-space()='Get email']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", myElement)
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='gprospect_linkedin_button gprospect_linkedin_button_style_medium'][normalize-space()='Get email']"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

Comment: can you give the website or the full html dump.

Comment: @Infern0 using getprospect plugin on chrome at linkedin website

Comment: @usertool Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjanB no error message but the button doesn't seem to be clicked, any way to print out if the button has been click?

Comment: @usertool Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjanB tried the update B, the button click didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'button') and contains(@class, 'gprospect_linkedin_button')]").click()
```